# Testing React app (at build time) for dead links and spelling mistakes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to add a step to my CI pipeline to validate the following on my React app:

- Validate that all `<a>` links are valid (no 404s)
- Spell check all text content of the website

I am hoping to find a generic JavaScript tool that I can simply point to the URL of my app for it to be crawled.